# Python Beginner: While Loop so long as item is in list

Tags: python

I am trying to make a Hangman game and implement a while loop with the condition below.  When I run it through Thonny the while loop comes back as false even though the variable display has that character in the list.

```
display = []
for _ in range(word_length):
    display += "_"

while "_" in display == True:
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
    for position in range(word_length):
        letter = chosen_word[position]
        if letter == guess:
            display[position] = letter

print(display)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Took out debugging code that wasn't relevant to question.

Comment: You don't need `display == True`.

Comment: also indenting the last line (print(display) once would make more sense, so you would see which letters are guessed correctly from the word

Comment: Could you provide the code that defines `word_length` and `chosen_word` ?

Answer (score 0):

`in` and `==` are both comparison operators, subject to comparison chaining. As a result, your unnecessary comparison to `True` makes this equivalent to

```
"_" in display and display == True
```

You could parenthesize it explicitly to disable chaining

```
("_" in display) == True
```

but you should just drop the `== True` altogether:

```
while "_" in display:
    ...
```